# Node.JS hosting basic webpage Error: ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, enoent

new to node.js and was following a basic tutorial at link below.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_web_module.htm

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

// Create a server
http.createServer( function (request, response) {  
   // Parse the request containing file name
   var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
   
   // Print the name of the file for which request is made.
   console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
   
   // Read the requested file content from file system
   fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         // HTTP Status: 404 : NOT FOUND
         // Content Type: text/plain
         response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      }else {   
         //Page found     
         // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
         // Content Type: text/plain
         response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});    
         
         // Write the content of the file to response body
         response.write(data.toString());       
      }
      // Send the response body 
      response.end();
   });   
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

created 2 files the index.html and the server.js completely identical to the post.
Then when i try to run it with

> node server.js

No error message shows up, but when i try to access the page on my browser it does not connect and an error shows up in the console.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

> Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
>
> Request for / received.
>
> { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '' errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '' }

Comment: Have you used the url as specified in the tutorial `http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.htm`? Especially the `index.htm` part at the end.

Comment: You always have to include the the relevant code within your question and not as link to a foreign site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the given code you have:

```
// Print the name of the file for which request is made.
console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

// Read the requested file content from file system
fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
```

Because the path is `/` the `pathname.substr(1)` will result in an empty string. And because you don't have a file that has no name, the `fs.readFile` does not find a file to read which results in an `ENOENT` error.

The given code does not automatically interpret an empty string as `index.html`.

So you either have to use `http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html` in the browser. Or change the logic of the code to interpret the empty string as `index.html`.

Comment: This makes so much sense. I assumed it only required my localhost and port number to access the hosted page. did not put in the index.html at the end. This also answers me as to why i never saw a reference to the index file.